# Node.js ajax call and display results with handlebars

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I currently have an image and when I click on the image I want to take the url of the image (which is the src) and then get the information associated with that image from my mongodb database. The way I'm trying to do it is to click on the image, get the url, then pass the url back to my routes file -> do a database query to get information and then pass back to page but the information is blank

My ajax call:

```
     $(function() {
$(".image_selection").click(function() {

  var idimg = $(this).attr('id');

  var data = {};
        data.img = idimg;
        var source, template;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: encodeURIComponent(idimg),

                      url: 'http://localhost:3001/new',
                      success: function(data) {
                          console.log('success');
                          console.log(data);

                      }
                  });


     $("#load_art").css({"visibility":"visible"});
     //$("#load_art").html({data});

     $(".image_selection1").attr('src',idimg);
     $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#load_art").offset().top},
        'slow');
    });
});
```

});

My route file:

```
    app.get('/new', function(req, res){
    var obj = {};
  var img = req.body.img;
    Images.find({'url':img}).limit(1).exec(function(err, docs){
       res.send({images:docs});
    });

});
```

Handlebars view should technically show me the raw data if I write {{images}} but nothing shows up. Any ideas?

In the console:

```
    success

Array[1]
0:Object
width: bla bla,
height: bla bla,
etc for each object element returned from database
```

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving your data dangling. The data from the ajax call is only available through the `success` function (it is asynchronous, meaning it returns some time later and the success function gets called with that data when it is available from your server).

So you will need to add logic in that function to trigger your handlebars template with the data returned:

```
$(function () {
  $(".image_selection").click(function () {
    var idimg = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data: encodeURIComponent(idimg),
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/new',
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var source   = $("#image-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(data);
        // you will now have some html that you will need to insert into your page
        $(".someplace").innerHTML = html;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

You will also need to provide a suitable Handlebars template so you can update your page from the client code. You will need something like this in your html:

```
<script id="image-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each items}}
    {{width}},{{height}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

The data you are getting is in an array, so you will need to use a #each handlebars construct.

Comment: can you recommend a way to capture the data and pass it to handlebars by any chance?

Comment: Your data is already there - the `data` parameter is the data returned from your ajax call. You can put a `console.log(data)' where my comments are to see that. After that you pass your data to your compiled handlebars template. Perhaps you could include your handlebars view in the question and I could guide you further.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is show a section of the handlebars page (with the data returned) when the ajax call is complete. I've updated the code above to show what I'm trying to achieve (scroll to the section of the page, show the image i've clicked on and then load the data I've retrieved from the database. The name of my handlebars file is /home

Comment: Its just a regular url for example "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp".. what I'm doing then is searching for that in my database and returning the object associated with it to get the values I need to display on the page @rasmeister

Comment: When I console.log(data) I can see the object in the console!

Comment: @ragmeister I have updated the code as above! thank you for the help by the way!

Comment: @rasmeister Hey I am facing a similar issue if you could help me out with it. I followed your answer, yet I am unable to get the data displayed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782023/using-ajax-in-node-js-and-displaying-data-using-handlebars.