# Using AJAX in Node js and displaying data using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, handlebars.js

I am using AJAX and Handlebars to get data from my MongoDB without refreshing the page and represent it in an easier manner.

I have created a div with a search button where a user places his/her inputs. These inputs need to passed to my routes and then the results from my DB should be sent back from my routes, to the handlebar which will help me display the products.

**index.hbs**

```
<div id="search-form">
....
                <input id="bhkInput" name="bmin" type="number">
                <input id="priceMin" name="pf" type="number">
                <input id="priceMax" name="pt" type="number">
               <input type="submit" class="btn searchButton" id="submit" value="Search" onclick="showResults()">
</div>

<div class="row col-sm-12 searchResults" id="sr">
//Results need to be displayed here
</div>


<script id = "result-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each searchResults }}
            <div class="row">
                {{#each this }}
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                       ...
                            <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" alt="..." class=" card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4>Flat No: {{this.flatNo}}</h4>
                                ...
                                <p class="description">
                                    {{this.description}}
                                </p>
                                ...
                                ...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
<script>
     function showResults(){
        let bmin = document.getElementById('bhkInput').value;
        let pf = document.getElementById('priceMin').value;
        let pt = document.getElementById('priceMax').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                bmin: bmin,
                pf: pf,
                pt: pt
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/results",
            success: function(data){
                let source = $('#result-template').html();
                let template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                let html = template(data);
                $(".searchResults").innerHTML = html;
            }

        });
}
```

The issue that I am facing:

When I send back the results from my DB, I am unable to display it using Handlebars.
How do I handle the data after success function is called. I want the results to be appended in the 'searchResults' div. I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395075/node-js-ajax-call-and-display-results-with-handlebars), however I am yet not able to see the data of my results.

**Update**

I took dummy data from the [Handlebars Docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/) and used it for my template and yet there is no data being appended in the html
The console.log(html) returns the template without the new data items

**index.hbs**

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
            {{body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script>
....
 $.ajax({
           ....
            success: function(data){
 var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
                var html    = template(context);
                console.log(html); 
....
</script>
```

**Output for console.log(html)**

```
  <div class="entry">
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="body">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue. Your method is `GET` so I think you can get it by `req.query.productId`.

For the second issue. You should append your data in ajax success callback function, because ajax is asynchronous. For example:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       data: encodeURIComponent(searchObject),
       url: "/results",
       success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
             let sr = document.getElementById('sr');
             $(sr).append();
       }
});
```

[How to get "data" from JQuery Ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700513/how-to-get-data-from-jquery-ajax-requests/27700607)

Comment: How do I access the different parameters of the searchResults without using handlebars and append it the way you have shown

Comment: Also please check the update. The req.query.productId  however it is not working

Comment: @rut_0_1 can you `console.log(req.query)`

Comment: { 'object Object': '' } is the Output of console.log(req.query)

Comment: @rut_0_1 In your ajax call you don't need to `encodeURIComponent`, just `data: searchObject`. jQuery will do encode work for you.

Comment: So, I solved the first issue that I was facing using few other questions and your comments however I am yet stuck on displaying the data using Handlebars

Comment: @rut_0_1 Can you try `console.log` the data in success and the html you got ? Try `$(".searchResults").html(html)`

Comment: Console.log of data returns my search results as an object Array which consists of JSON objects as array elements. And $(".searchResults").html(html) is not working.

Comment: @rut_0_1 then you have to make sure that your html is working, that why I ask you to `console.log(html)` to see if handlebars can render your html correctly. From handlebars document, it's `#each`, I'm not sure that `# each` working or not.

Comment: console.log(html) returns an empty object, and I have updated my answer to {{#each}} however there is not difference

Comment: @rut_0_1 In that case, I think the problem is how you structure your return data. From your template it should be have `searchResults: [ { imagePath: '', flatNo: '', } ]`

Comment: So i ditched my data and went ahead with the data and method mentioned in the docs, however there is no data being appended. Check the update